# Reason behind making http stateless

Tags: http, stateless

I want to know the reason behind making the http stateless.
There should be some reason in making the http stateless.
I searched the  whole internet and found nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find this quote from [Roy Thomas Fielding's Architectural Styles and
the Design of Network-based Software Architectures](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm) helpful.  This is about REST which is particular way of using HTTP:

> We next add a constraint to the client-server interaction: communication must be stateless in nature [...] This constraint induces the properties of visibility, reliability, and scalability.